# How to access the index of a MaterialUI StepConnector

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am using a [Stepper component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/), and I would like to style the connectors individually based on their index. The need to be able to access the index of the current step from within `StepConnector` came up in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30900) in February, and [a PR was accepted](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/31021) to make this easy with `useStepContext`. I'm using the current version of MaterialUI, 5.10.4.

However, I'm getting an empty object back instead of the context I'm expecting with the index. This happens with both approaches. The only difference I can see between what I'm doing and the [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-v5-stepconnector-does-not-return-any-index-props-without-passing-it-from-the-instance-forked-bnht2?file=/package.json) from the GitHub issue is that I'm on 5.10.4 and the sample is using 5.4.0. But perhaps I'm missing something?

Here is my code. The easy way:

```js
import { useStepContext } from "@mui/material/Step/StepContext";
import StepConnector from "@mui/material/StepConnector";

function CIConnector(props) {
    const ctx = useStepContext();
    console.log("context:", ctx);

  return (
    <StepConnector />
  );
}
```

The hard way, suggested as a workaround in the original issue before the PR was accepted:

```jsx
import * as React from "react";
import StepContext from "@mui/material/Step/StepContext";
import StepConnector from "@mui/material/StepConnector";

function CIConnector(props) {
    const ctx = React.useContext(StepContext);
    console.log("context:", ctx);

  return (
    <StepConnector />
  );
}
```

In this second version, when I break in the debugger, `StepContext` is `undefined`. But if I step into `useContext()`, it seems to correctly receive the `StepContext` object. Still, it's returning an empty object.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I have gotten a [minimal test](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-framework-9occso?file=/src/App.tsx) to fail too, so I have [opened a bug with MUI](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/34228).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way I was importing the method. This code works on MaterialUI 5.10.17:

```js
import { StepConnector, useStepContext } from "@mui/material/Step";

function CIConnector(props) {
    const ctx = useStepContext();
    console.log("context:", ctx);

  return (
    <StepConnector />
  );
}
```